# Is magento 2 open source version support Business to Business ( B2B) and Business to Customer(B2C) system?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, b2b

I have setup a ***magento 2(open source)*** store and i want a ***B2B*** and ***B2C*** ecommerce system for my store where ***suppliers*** can upload their products and view ***revenues*** and ***reports***. And ***customers*** can also login with  their credentials and view the details of shopped products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No - By default with Magento 2 (Open Source ) there is no functionality related to B2B system.**

**Open source is only used for B2C kind of services where buyer can sell the products and customer can purchase the products.**

But There are some third party **plugins/Extensions is available** to achieve this kind of functionality in Magento 2 open source as well . so if you want to achieve you must need to go with those kind of extensions and need to do customization on the same.

On the other side or considering alternative option -  Magento Commerce(known as Magento Enterprise Edition) - **Have in built functionalities of B2B related stuffs so you can use it for the same(But again your required some customization based on your business nature)**. Here is the reference link - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/b2b/bk-b2b.html

Comment: Is any free third party extension available ?

Comment: @MohdHasan - No , as you are see its very immense and composite functionality so there is no free third party extension is available you must need to purchase it for the same

Comment: - yeah, i will try to purchase

Comment: sure, i will accept